# update content of column from another schema.table.column postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have 2 schemas in the same database (postgresql).

`schema1`

`schema2`

Each schema has table `users` and `mail column`.

**how can i copy the content from mail column in schema1.users to mail column to schema2.users for all rows**

i tried:

```
update schema1.users
set mail=(select mail from schema2.users);
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You can do an UPDATE joining the tables, assuming both of your tables have matching ID's, it'll look like this:

```
UPDATE schema1.users a
SET mail=b.mail
FROM schema2.users b
WHERE a.id=b.id
```

What I'm doing is Joining the tables and updating mail on schema1.users for every matching id.

***EDIT:*** I just read that you actually wanted to update the schema2.users mails. The query will be this one:

```
UPDATE schema2.users a
SET mail=b.mail
FROM schema1.users b
WHERE a.id=b.id
```

Answer (score 1):

you can join the two tables. I joined on user but i don't know what the tablelayout looks like.

```
update schema2.users 
set mail=s1.mail
from schema1.mail as s1
where users.user = s1.user
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an elegant solution but this is what I am doing from the command line in a script to copy a specific table from one schema to a specific table in a different schema

```
set search_path to schema1;   

\copy (select field1, nextfield, morefields from table_in_schema1 ) TO export.sql delimiter ',' ;

set search_path to schema2; 

\copy table_name_in_schema2(matchingfield1, field_that_matches_next, another_field_forPosition2, ) FROM 'export.sql' DELIMITER ',' ;
```

I have several tables that I need to export to a single table in the new schema so I have this scripted so I have a loop that reads a file containing the table names to import into schema two and then send them to the database by using the command below - which will load around 30 tables to the table in the second schema.

```
psql -d alltg -c "\i bulk_import.sql"
```

Comment: This is silly. A simple `update` as shown in the existing answers will do.